# reverse for 'topic' not found. 'topic' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python3 and Django and I am trying to build a small webapp by following instructions from a book. I have been trying other solutions find online like using " instead of ' or change the name of the template 'topic' that does not work as its name was too close from another template 'topics' of the app which might have caused trouble for Django. Here are my three files:

urls.py

```
"""Defines URL patterns for learning_logs"""

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name= 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns=[
    #Home Page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # Topic Page
    path('topic/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
]

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Topic


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    """The home page for Learning Log"""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics= Topic.objects.order_by('data_added')
    context= {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries"""
    topic= Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries= topic.entry_set.order_by('-data_added')
    context= {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
`
```

topic.html

{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

```
<p>Topic: {{ sujet }}</p>

<p>Entries:</p>
<ul>
{% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
        <p> {{entry.data_added|date: 'M d, Y H:i'}}</p>
        <p>{{entry.text|linebreaks}}</p>
    </li>
{% empty %}
    <li>There are no entries for this topic yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

{% endblock content %}

Here is what my base.html and topics.html (linked to topic.html) look like:

```
base.html
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
</p>

{% block content %} {% endblock content %}



topics.html

{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <p>Topics</p>

    <ul>
        {% for topic in topics %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'learning_logs: topic' topic_id %}"> {{ topic }}</a>
            </li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No topics have been added yet. </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock content%}
```

Thanks guys for your help, I hope I provided enough details for you guys to answer

Answer (score 1):

`topic_id` is not a parameter you passed to the template, you can obtain the `id` of `topic` with:

```
<a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the command does not work unfortunately. I’ve used .id and _id differently because I was told that topic.id examines a topic and retrieves the value of the corresponding ID whereas topic_id is a reference to that ID in the code.

Comment: @AlexandreLocci: there was also a spacing problem in the name of the url: it is `'learning_logs:topic'`, not `learning_logs: topic`.

Comment: @AlexandreLocci: furthermore `topic.id` indeed exampines a `topic`, but `topic_id` simply does not exists here. You only pass `topics` to the view.

Comment: @AlexandreLocci: you are likely confusing using a `someobject.foreignkey.id` over `someobject_foreignkey_id`, in that case, it is indeed better to use the latter to avoid an extra query, but here you *already* made the query when fetching all `topics` into memory, so you do not make an extra roundtrip to the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help everything works perfectly! Indeed I also had a foreignkey problem